# changing `sibling distance` and `level distance` in the middle

Tags: tikz-trees

I have the following decision tree I am trying to fit in one page. The output looks like the following. The MWE follows.

Note that as the tree grows to the fourth bottom node `doses given` it has 4 child nodes. This takes up too much space and is forced off the page. Another problem is that the `path 7` node boxes overlap the boxes from the `age` node... (they are not the same! just a matter of geometry adding up).

I also have quite a bit of empty white space I'd like to fill up. In this sense, it would be nice to have 90 degree nodes rather than angled nodes.

[image: mwe example]

```
% Scenario tree
% Author: Rasmus Pank Roulund
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow=down,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6.3cm,level distance=3.5cm},
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black, %blue!40!black!60
        shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
    %edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    kant/.style={text width=2cm, text centered, sloped},
    every node/.style={text ragged, inner sep=2mm},
    punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, top color=white,
    bottom color=white, draw=black, very
    thick }
    ]
\node[punkt, text width=5.5em] {Health at infection}
    %Lower part lv1
    child {
        node[punkt] [rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
         text ragged] {
            \textbf{Path 6}
            \nodepart{second}
            $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
            \nodepart{third}
            $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
        }
        edge from parent
            node[kant, above] {Recovered}
    }
    %Upper part, lv1
    child {
        node[punkt] {previous infection?} 
        %child 1 %% "yes" child
        child {
            node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                \textbf{Path 7}
                \nodepart{second}
                $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                \nodepart{third}
                $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
            }
            edge from parent
            node[below, kant] {Yes} % node[below, kant,  pos=.6] {Yes}
        }
        %child 2
        child {
            node [punkt]{is vaccinated?}
            child{
                node[punkt]{age}
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{ \textgreater{1825}} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{ \textless{1825}} 
                }
                edge from parent
                    node[kant, above]{No}
            } 
            child{
                node[punkt]{Doses Given}
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{1} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{2} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{3} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{4} 
                }
                edge from parent
                    node[kant, above]{Yes}
            } 
            edge from parent
                node[kant, above] {No}
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[kant, above] {From Susceptible}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Kind of looking for something similar to the tree presented here: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/fault-tree/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. Even though I have `grow=down` defined at a "global" level, I can redefine this at the node level. Now I have

[image]

with the code

```
% Scenario tree
% Author: Rasmus Pank Roulund
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow=down,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6.3cm,level distance=3.5cm},
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black, %blue!40!black!60
        shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
    %edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    kant/.style={text centered, sloped}, %text width=2cm
    every node/.style={text ragged, inner sep=2mm},
    punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, top color=white, bottom color=white, draw=black, very thick }
    ]
\node[punkt, text width=5.5em] {Health at infection}
    %Lower part lv1
    child {
        node[punkt] [rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
         text ragged] {
            \textbf{Path 6}
            \nodepart{second}
            $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
            \nodepart{third}
            $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
        }
        edge from parent
            node[kant, above] {recovered}
    }
    %Upper part, lv1
    child {
        node[punkt] {previous infection?} 
        %child 1 %% "yes" child
        child {
            node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                \textbf{Path 7}
                \nodepart{second}
                $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                \nodepart{third}
                $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
            }
            edge from parent
            node[below, kant] {Yes} % node[below, kant,  pos=.6] {Yes}
        }
        %child 2
        child {
            node [punkt]{is vaccinated?}[grow=right]
            child{
                node[punkt]{Doses Given}[grow=down]
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{1} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{2} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{3} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{4} 
                }
                edge from parent
                    node[kant, above]{Yes}
            }
            child{
                node[punkt]{age}
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{ \textgreater{1825}} 
                }
                child{
                    node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3] {
                        \textbf{Path 7}
                        \nodepart{second}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{carriage}) = (0, 0)$
                        \nodepart{third}
                        $\mathcal{P}(\text{invasive}) = (0, 0)$
                    }
                    edge from parent
                        node[kant, above]{ \textless{1825}} 
                }
                edge from parent
                    node[kant, above]{No}
            }             
            edge from parent
                node[kant, above] {No}
        }
        edge from parent{
            node[kant, above] {From Susceptible}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found the solution based on masfenix' solution code. However, I think my solution is simpler. Thus I'm going to add it, for those who google the same thing 2 years later, just like I did:

masfenix defined the following global variable in their tikzpicture:
`level 1/.style={sibling distance=6.3cm,level distance=3.5cm},`

So, I thought, what if I try the same thing for each level, so I can set the distances for each level globally?

And, lo and behold, adding

```
level 2/.style={sibling distance=xy cm,level distance=xy cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=xy cm,level distance=xy cm},
and so on...
```

does what I want it to do. Success!